# Python - How to run array batches

Tags: python, arrays, multithreading

I am new to Python and I am currently working on a multiple webpage scraper. While I was playing around with Python I found out about Threading, this really speeds up the code. The problem is that the script scrapes lots of sites and I like to this in an array of 'batches' while using Threading.

When I've got an array of 1000 items I'd like to grab 10 items. When the script is done with these 10 items, grab 10 new items until there is nothing left

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

```
import subprocess
import threading
from multiprocessing import Pool

def scrape(url):
    return subprocess.call("casperjs test.js --url=" + url, shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    sites = ["http://site1.com", "http://site2.com", "http://site3.com", "http://site4.com"]

    results = pool.imap(scrape, sites)

    for result in results:
        print(result)
```

In the future I use an sqlite database where I store all the URLs (this will replace the array). When I run the script I want the control of stopping the process and continue whenever I want to. This is not my question but the context of my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "array"?

Comment: @Jan showing what your currently doing (code) would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry. I've add the code I currently have

Comment: If you set the pool to a specific size, like `pool = Pool(10)`, then you can feed all `1000` urls to it an it will parcel out the work so that no more than `10` threads run at the same time until they're all processed.

Comment: Note, you are working with a *list* not an *array*.

Comment: You could use `results = pool.map(scrape, sites)` or `results = list(pool.imap(scrape, sites))` I believe.

Answer (score 2):

> **Question**: ... array of 1000 items I'd like to grab 10 items

```
for p in range(0, 1000, 10):
    process10(sites[p:p+10])
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Process` and `Queue` from `multiprocessing`? Writing a worker function and calling it from a loop makes it run as batches. With `Process`, jobs can be started and stopped when needed and give you more control over them.

```
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def worker(url_queue, result_queue):
    for url in iter(url_queue.get, 'DONE'):
        scrape_result = scrape(url)
        result_queue.put(scrape_result)


def scrape(url):
    return subprocess.call("casperjs test.js --url=" + url, shell=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sites = ['http://site1.com', "http://site2.com", "http://site3.com", "http://site4.com", "http://site5.com",
             "http://site6.com", "http://site7.com", "http://site8.com", "http://site9.com", "http://site10.com",
             "http://site11.com", "http://site12.com", "http://site13.com", "http://site14.com", "http://site15.com",
             "http://site16.com", "http://site17.com", "http://site18.com", "http://site19.com", "http://site20.com"]
    url_queue = Queue()
    result_queue = Queue()
    processes = []

    for url in sites:
        url_queue.put(url)

    for i in range(10):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(url_queue, result_queue))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
        url_queue.put('DONE')

    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    result_queue.put('DONE')

    for response in iter(result_queue.get, 'DONE'):
        print response
```

Note that `Queue` is the FIFO Queue that supports putting and pulling elements.